# Import text from txt file into button text (html)

Tags: javascript, html, button, text-files

I have this button in my html file:

```
<button id="btn1" name="subject" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="html_j">kll</button>
```

And then I have a SendButton.txt file with the id 'sendBtn' in which I have just 1 row:

```
Send Message
```

I want that the message from the .txt file to be the text for the button. Any hints, please? T_T

I've tried successfully to set a default message to the button by writing this in main.js:

```
var y = document.getElementById('sendBtn');
y.innerText = "Sendddd"
```

But I don't know how to import the text from a file...

Comment: Client-side javascript can't read files that are stored on the server's local file server.

Comment: use .js file even to store variables and then your script can read those values.
Ex: 
variable.js ```window. text = "Send Message";```

Comment: @Vikramaditya can you explain a little more, please?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. You can read/write to a file using Node.js. It is not possible to read the contents of the file from frontend.